# Should Go Set A Watchman be read before To Kill A Mockingbird?

Tags: reading-order, to-kill-a-mockingbird, harper-lee, go-set-a-watchman

Given that *Go Set A Watchman* takes place after *To Kill A Mockingbird*, we would think that we should read it second. However, *Go Set A Watchman* was probably a first draft of *To Kill A Mockingbird*. I am not really sure in which order they should be read given these two pieces of conflicting information. Which of these should be read first?

Comment: I think a better question might be "Should *Go Set a Watchman* be considered a prequel or a first draft?" Because you would read those for two very different reasons, and that would be much more helpful in determining which to read first.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I take your point. Would you like to edit that in? If not, I will.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Definitely read *To Kill a Mockingbird* first. Although *Go Set a Watchman* reads more as a first draft of *To Kill a Mockingbird*, without reading Mockingbird, much of the bigotry Atticus displays in Watchman will not be unusual. In Mockingbird, Atticus is portrayed as a hero defending the underprivileged blacks, and in Watchman, that illusion of him is completely shattered.

They're both great reads, but reading *To Kill a Mockingbird* first allows you to have a greater conceptual understanding and appreciation for *Go Set a Watchman*.