# Should Go Set a Watchman be read as a prequel, or an early draft?

Tags: harper-lee, go-set-a-watchman

It was established in [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/131/should-go-set-a-watchman-be-read-before-to-kill-a-mockingbird) that *Go Set a Watchman* should be read after *To Kill A Mockingbird*. However, in the comments, LaurenIpsum pointed out that a better question might be "Should *Go Set a Watchman* be considered a prequel or a first draft?" So, I modified it slightly to ask:

Should *Go Set a Watchman* be read as a prequel or a first draft?

Note: This question is not about the reading order, it's about the style of *Go Set a Watchman* and what to consider it as when reading it.

Comment: Does this edit help clarify a bit?

Comment: The edit does help to clarify, @Riker. Benjamin, I apologize for suggesting an edit without fully understanding your question. I suppose that might be part of the reason my edits still require approval ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, I guess first drafts make great prequels, and should definitely be read afterwards. Think of *The Hobbit*, a lighter, less tense éclairage on *The Lord of the Rings*, which irony can only be perceived if Tolkien's masterpiece was read beforehand.

*Go Set a Watchman* does not escape this: the social tension that makes the book interesting can escape a reader - and certainly was much less central for the author - than in *To Kill A Mockingbird*, and for this reason reading the former in the light of the later would be my recommendation.

Comment: IMO *The Hobbit* should be your gateway drug to Tolkien. *The Fellowship of the Ring* is too dry to read as an entry into the universe, as a youth.